# When is a subset dense in $R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $A$ has only finitely many boundary points, I expect that $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I can not prove this.

Can anybody help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to mention that $A$ is open.

Comment: For example $(0,1)$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I upvoted ziggurism's comment. That said, it is clear that $n=1$ is an exception.

Comment: @ziggurism what if we add the stipulation n > 1?

Comment: For example $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: But $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ has infinite boundary points. {0,1}x [0,1] $\cup$ [0,1]x{0,1}

Comment: As a manifold with boundary, the boundary is empty. But I guess you meant boundary in the topological subspace sense?

Comment: I assume that's what "finite boundary points" in the OP meant, yes.

Comment: @S.Liu - Could you please explain the reasoning behind your expectation so that we may provide a more satisfying answer to you?

Answer (score 0):

When **$n >1$.**

Assume by contradiction that $A$ is not dense in $\mathbb R^n$.

Then there exists an open set $U$ such that $U \subset \mathbb R^n \backslash \overline{A}$.

Now, pick some $x \in A$ and $y \in U$.

Find infinitely many pairwise disjsoint paths $\gamma_n :[0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$ which start at $x$ and end at $y$. This is possible for all $n>1$, but not for $n=1$.

For each path $\gamma_n$ show that for 
$$t_n:= \sup \{s \in [0,1]| \gamma_n(s) \in A \}$$
the point $\gamma_n(t_n)$ is a boundary point for $A$.

As the paths are pairwise disjoint, we have infinitely many distinct boundary points.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\in A$ and suppose $u$ is not in the closure of your set (and that $n\geq 2$).
Consider the rays $r_v: t\in {\Bbb R}_+ \mapsto u+tv$ with $v\in S^{n-1}$. Then
for $n=(a-u)/|a-u|$ the ray $r_n$ will intersect the boundary of $A$. And so will every ray in a neighborhood $U\subset S^{n-1}$ of $n$. This neighborhood $U$ is uncountable when $n\geq 2$.

A bit more work and you may show that the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure of $\partial A$ must be non-zero.